# How to 'translate' an async function inside of componentDidMount to an async function inside of UseEffect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am watching a course on Firebase which was taught with class components, but I am working with function components. This is how the teacher does it

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const snapshot = await firestore.collection('posts').get()
  console.log({ snapshot })
}
```

And this is how I've tried to do but am not sure if it's right

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getSnapshot() {
      const snapshot = await firestore.collection('posts').get()
      console.log({ snapshot })
    }
    getSnapshot()
  }, [])
```

I am not sure it is working right because for the teacher, the return value is

```
{snapshot: QuerySnapshot}
```

and I am getting

```
{snapshot: t}
```

edit: this is how I am creating the store

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { FIREBASE_KEY } from '../constants/Keys'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: `${FIREBASE_KEY}`,
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...', 
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  appId: '...',
  measurementId: '...',
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const firestore = firebase.firestore()

export default firebase
```

and simply importing it as

```
import { firestore } from '../../Firebase/Firebase'
```

Comment: The way you have written it is actually correct

Comment: so that can only mean I am not using firebase/firestore correctly (because of the return value). Any thoughts?

Comment: how do you create fireStore in both the cases

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  edited the question to (hopefully) reflect that

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncCallback = async () => {
    // async callback
  };

  asyncCallback();
}, [dep]);
```

Solution 2:

```
useEffect(() => {(async () => {
  // async IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
})()}, [dep]);
```

Solution 3:

```
const asyncCallback = useCallback(async () => {
  // async callback
}, [dep]);

useEffect(() => {
  asyncCallback()
}, [asyncCallback]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSnapshot` to get away from the need of async,

---

```
    firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => console.log({ snapshot }))
```

---